# Cannot display webkit Inspector in ultralight c++

Tags: c++, webkit

I am trying to add an inspector to use for debugging. I am using ultralight and tried following their documentation but was only successful with bundling inspector with my build.

My current code to attempt displaying inspector looks like this:

```
explicit WebGUI(WebGUIConfig config)
    {
        this->functionMap = config.getFunctionMap();
        app = ultralight::App::Create();
        window = ultralight::Window::Create(app->main_monitor(), config.width, config.height, false,
                                            ultralight::kWindowFlags_Titled | ultralight::kWindowFlags_Resizable *
                                            config.isResizable);
        app->set_window(*window);
        window->SetTitle(config.title.c_str());
        overlay = ultralight::Overlay::Create(*window, window->width(), window->height(), 0, 0);
        overlay->view()->set_load_listener(this);
        overlay->view()->LoadURL(config.url.c_str());
        window->set_listener(this);
        overlay->view()->set_view_listener(this);

        ultralight::RefPtr<ultralight::View> inspectorView = overlay->view()->inspector();
        inspectorView->Resize(500, 500);
        auto inspectorViewView = ultralight::Overlay::Create(*window, *inspectorView, 0, 0);
        inspectorViewView->view()->set_load_listener(this);
        inspectorViewView->view()->set_view_listener(this);
    }
```

I can see many errors in the debug console (most of them are syntax exceptions), but I dont see any inspector window appearing.
Am I doing something wrong? How do I display this view?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer this is not a full answer.

I used the [quickstart](https://docs.ultralig.ht/docs/writing-your-first-app) to start my project, then :

In MyApp.h :

```
RefPtr<Overlay> inspector_overlay_;
```

In MyApp.cpp :

```
MyApp::MyApp()
{
    app_ = App::Create();
    window_ = Window::Create(app_->main_monitor(), WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT,
                             false, kWindowFlags_Titled | kWindowFlags_Resizable);
    overlay_ = Overlay::Create(window_, 1, 1, 0, 0);


    OnResize(window_.get(), window_->width(), window_->height());
    overlay_->view()->LoadURL("file:///index.html");

    app_->set_listener(this);
    window_->set_listener(this);
    overlay_->view()->set_load_listener(this);
    overlay_->view()->set_view_listener(this);
    overlay_->view()->CreateLocalInspectorView();
}

RefPtr<View> MyApp::OnCreateInspectorView(ultralight::View* caller, bool is_local,
    const String& inspected_url) {
    if (inspector_overlay_)
        return nullptr;

    inspector_overlay_ = Overlay::Create(window_, window_->width(), 200, 0, 150);

    caller->Resize(window_->width(), window_->height());
    inspector_overlay_->Show();
    return inspector_overlay_->view();
}
```

But with that I am not able to interact with the overlay view (I am probably missing some event handling ?). So I used the [browser sample](https://github.com/ultralight-ux/Samples/tree/master/Sample%208%20-%20Web%20Browser) and replace one of the html file of one of the tab with my files, I also added the `/inspector` folder from the source in the asset folder and fix the `CMakeLists.txt` file. Then it was working properly so you should be able to extract what you need from there.

If you make it work in your project I am interested as well :)